# How do I fix my Application.java to work with the new version of Firebase_messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've upgraded all my firebase packages today, and I had to upgrade to version 8.0.0-dev.13 for firebase messaging even though it is still in dev due to dependency issues. In Application.Java, I have:

```
package com.halloglobal.flutterapp.hallo;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
import io.flutter.view.FlutterMain;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
@override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
}
@override
public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
}
}
```

Which has worked fine in the past, but now with this new version, I get this error:
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/hallo/Documents/HalloMonoRepo/hallo/android/app/src/main/java/com/halloglobal/flutterapp/hallo/Application.java:7: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging does not exist
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
^
/Users/hallo/Documents/HalloMonoRepo/hallo/android/app/src/main/java/com/halloglobal/flutterapp/hallo/Application.java:8: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging does not exist
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;

How do I need to change my Application.java to work with the new version?

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it by removing the plugin registration completely, the new version handles it internally now.

Comment: do you have the source for that claim?

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/#3-android-integration
and
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/
specifically pay attention to stuff about v2 embedding.

Comment: You're a life saver :)

Comment: do you have the source for that claim?

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me. Maybe will help you.if there is something you don't use, remove it like flutter local notification.
Also you can check this article
https://medium.com/@demmydwirhamadan/working-well-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-in-flutter-tested-on-android-4eb91f45d45

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {

        if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
            return;
        }
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
    }
    private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        final String key = Application.class.getCanonicalName();
        if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
            return true;
        }
        registry.registrarFor(key);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add this in your dependency - pubspec.yaml

firebase_messaging: